# Ctrl key not working Thinkpad SL510

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, thinkpad, shortcuts

Today I got a new keyboard for my Thinkpad SL510, I noticed though that my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key wasn't working, I tried both and neither worked, but when I used both and pressed <kbd>v</kbd> also, it typed "5v" with other key combos it does other things, so the keys themselves cannot be physically broken as nothing happens when I just use one and press <kbd>v</kbd> other than v being typed, I plugged in an external keyboard and the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys on that worked perfectly, this only happened after I rebooted, a reboot is not helping either, What can I do? my guess is it is a problem with keyboard layout.

Comment: List of key combos with both ctrls that happen:  c+F2,  m+6, v+5, x+F1, z+~, >+F8, and <+=

Answer (score 1):

Weird.  My best suggestion would be to check your keyboard layout is correct in settings - and maybe your bios if it was sold outside the US.

These might help:

http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Keyboard-Layout-in-Ubuntu

[How do I change default keyboard layout (not input method) in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765015/how-do-i-change-default-keyboard-layout-not-input-method-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Nope, didn't work, I changed the keyboard layout multiple times but none worked.